# How to give Connection String for Sql lite database?

Tags: java, sqlite

First of all i would like to tell my apologies for asking this simple question. i am trying to connect sql-lite database table.I am using following code.

```
package derb;
import java.sql.*;
public class db {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/anand/MySQLiteDB.TEST","root","ROOT");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String q="insert into CHECKING values(3)";
        st.executeUpdate(q);
    }

}
```

**TEST** is my database and i created one table called **CHECKING** in eclipse.but in above code gives me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: no such table: CHECKING
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:102)
    at derb.db.main(db.java:9)
```

I manually  checked in the eclipse the table was available.but i don't know how to make the connection to that table.So any one can help me to fix this

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you try to run the same statement through the sqlite command line interface?

Comment: @immibis in eclipse i generated ddl (.sql) file and write my queries it will execute correctly.I think the problem is in my connection string that's why my table not detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just now i come to know my mistake i just remove my db name from the connection string it works fine for me.

**Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/anand/MySQLiteDB.TEST","root","ROOT");**

changed to

```
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/anand/MySQLiteDB","root","ROOT");
```